# In Neo4j can lucene process data to modify/aggregate nodes before indexing it?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

So lets say I am modelling a paragraph with chunks of text as children, but I want the indexer to operate on the whole paragraph text. Rather than duplicate the text into to the paragraph, or change the model, is there a method to get the indexer to reconstitute the paragraph (by simply joining all children) before it index's it? i.e. it does some processing before it index's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using manual legacy indexing (also required to use FTS in lucene) you basically pass the value and the node you want it to point to. The value doesn't even need to be a property on the node.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-add-node-to-index

In this case, you'd have to do that processing on your side, but it's doable.

Comment: Is the legacy indexing going to be phased out? If I'm choosing a structure based on being able to do this, I don't want to be hamstrung by it later on... is it just the legacy indexing INTERFACE? Or is it indexing itself now using a different version or format (i.e. I won't be able to leverage features put in in future versions of Neo4j)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the plans for the legacy indexing are, but I'm sure they won't remove it until the features I mentioned (FTS) are available in the new indexes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use another form of lucene to point to the paragraph nodes in your Neo, with polyglot persistence. With elastic search or solr, perhaps?

Comment: Good idea. I reckon search is all we need that for... it's unlikely to feature in OLTP queries (I have been tossing up whether to store everything one level up to make it easier for OLTP).